# eal_memory.c:56:18: fatal error: numa.h: No such file or directory

Tags: centos7, dpdk

When I execute `make` from the [quick start](http://dpdk.org/doc/quick-start) instruction for DPDK, I get the following error:

```
eal_memory.c:56:18: fatal error: numa.h: No such file or directory
```

The error comes out even when libnuma is installed already:

```
>sudo yum install numactl-libs.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * elrepo: mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn
Package numactl-libs-2.0.9-6.el7_2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I'm using CenOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core).

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to install `numactl-devel`:

```
sudo yum install numactl-devel
```

Comment: When I try this, I get `No package libnuma-devel available.` Would you know what to do?

Comment: @kurt Well, it could be named `numactl-devel` or similarly. Anyway, you need development package, it comes with the missing headers...

Comment: i tried `sudo yum install numactl-devel.x86_64` for 64-bit machine, and it works. thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 11):

numa.h is also part of `libnuma` package.

Please install libnuma package:

CentOS 6.9: `yum install libnuma-devel`

Ubuntu: `apt-get install libnuma-dev`

Looks like on CentOS 7 docker container libnuma-devel is not available. In that case try `yum install numactl-devel`

Comment: on Centos:7 docker container yum install libnuma-devel not found, numactl-devel is found